# Any way to read a file and get list of modules defined in that file in Elixir without using ParallelCompiler methods?

Tags: elixir

[`Kernel.ParallelCompiler.compile/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.ParallelCompiler.html#compile/2) and [`Kernel.ParallelCompiler.require/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.ParallelCompiler.html#require/2) return `{:ok, modules, warnings}` when passing in a list of files such as `["example_file.ex", "example_file.exs"]`...

Let's say you have already compiled your files containing your modules with a previous call to `compile/2`.

Is there a way to get a list of modules contained in a particular file in Elixir without calling `compile/2` or `require/2`?

Comment: This sounds pretty much as [`XY Problem`](http://xyproblem.info/). Please share what are you actually trying to accomplish. Maybe [`Code.ensure_compiled?/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Code.html?#ensure_compiled?/1) would be your friends here. Please note, that there is no way to accomplish a task by static code analysis because e.g. both the module name and the module itself might be created dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Regex.scan/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#scan/3):

```
file_path = "./lots_of_modules.ex"
{:ok, contents} = File.read(file_path)
pattern = ~r{defmodule \s+ ([^\s]+) }x
Regex.scan(pattern, contents, capture: :all_but_first)
|> List.flatten()
```

output:

```
["MyApp.UserManager.User", "Stuff", "Dog.Owner", "Pet.Cat.Meow"]
```

If you need the module names as atoms:

```
  def get_modules() do
    file_path = "lib/lots_of_modules.ex"

    app_dir = File.cwd!
    absolute_file_path = Path.join([app_dir, file_path])

    {:ok, contents} = File.read(absolute_file_path)

    pattern = ~r{defmodule \s+ (\S+) }x  # \S is equivalent to [^\s]

    Regex.scan(pattern, contents, capture: :all_but_first)
    |> Enum.map(fn [name] -> 
                  String.to_existing_atom("Elixir.#{name}") 
                end)
  end
```

output:

```
[MyApp.UserManager.User, Stuff, Dog.Owner, Pet.Cat.Meow]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won’t work with [`Module.create/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Module.html?#create/3), making the whole approach less than robust. I have several projects containing hundreds of modules with zero `defmodule` calls.

Comment: Also, it returns incorrect (not fully qualified, to be precise) names for nested modules.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin,  *I have several projects containing hundreds of modules with zero defmodule calls.* It looks like you'll have to count them by hand at runtime, then enter them at a prompt.  :)

Comment: `:application.get_key(:my_app, :modules)` 